# pip not showing correct version

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I already had python3.8 installed and I installed python3.4 from its source code.

I wanted pip==19.1.1 as it is supported in python3.4. After installing pip when I tried changing its version but it was showing different version as you can see in the attached image.

Is there a way to use pip with version 19.1.1?

Thank you in advance.

```
remus@remus-VirtualBox:~$ python3.4 --version
Python 3.4.0
remus@remus-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt install python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (20.0.2-5ubuntu1.6).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
remus@remus-VirtualBox:~$ pip install pip==19.1.1
Collecting pip==19.1.1
  Using cached pip-19.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.8 are installed in '/home/remus/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pip-19.1.1
remus@remus-VirtualBox:~$ pip -V
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

[Terminal Image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQnJK.png)

OS: UBUNTU 20.04.4(Focal)

Comment: Hi, some quick thoughts: a) Maybe you'd get better answers on askubuntu.com, and b) if you could paste the things from your screenshot, it will make life easier for future people with the same problem to find your question

Comment: In general, having multiple python installations is the source of some pain and confusion. Is there a reason why you could not use something like `venv` or `conda` to distinguish your python versions?

Comment: @lucidbrot I've installed python3.4 using source code and it does not come with pip. I have to install pip either from its source code or using pip itself. I tried creating ` venv` but the pip version was still the same and not what I desired.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to use something like [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) or [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) to create your environments. That would allow you the hassle of having to distinguish multiple python binaries on your machine.

That said, I think your issue can be resolved by explicitly using the right python version by launching pip like this:

```
python3.4 -m pip --version
```

For example, I have two different python versions installed (shame on me!) and this is the output I get:

```
generic@motorbrot:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.17
generic@motorbrot:~$ python -m pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
generic@motorbrot:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
generic@motorbrot:~$ python3 -m pip --version
pip 21.1.2 from /home/generic/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

Comment: I ran `python3.4 -m pip --version` and got `/usr/local/bin/python3.4: No module named pip`

Comment: Then you're best off using an alternative environment, or you install pip using the `get-pip.py`